# multiply array of matrices by a vector

Tags: python, vector, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have an array of matrices that I want to multiply by a vector (so the first array in the matrix should be multiplied by the first value in the vector, etc.).

```
import numpy as np

# Three matrices/double arrays                                              
a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[2,3], [4, 5]])
c = np.array([[3,4], [5, 6]])

# An array of matrices                                                      
d = np.array([a, b, c])

# A vector                                                                  
e = np.array([1,2,3])

# Multiply every matrix by the corresponding value in the vector            
f = [ d[i] * e[i] for i in range(len(e)) ]

# Somewhat to my surpise however, this doesn't work                         
g = d * e # <-- Doesn't work

# Nor does                                                                  
h = e * d # <-- Doesn't work
```

So the list comprehension works, but I somehow doubt if that is the most efficient way of doing things.

Am I overlooking something really simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align the axes:

```
f = d * e[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]

d.shape
(3, 2, 2)
e.shape
(3,)
e[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis].shape
(3, 1, 1)
```

An alternative would be to make `d`'s shape (2,2,3), then `e` (with shape (3,)) would be broadcast-able to `d`'s shape.

What you really want is to learn more about [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

EDIT:

as for your second question, for inplace multiplication:

```
d *= e[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
```

No copies are created.

Comment: Also, form what it looks like, I get the impression the matrices are copied, right..?!?
Could I do a similar trick on d (as that would be cheaper, I think)\

Comment: OK, one other question... ;-) A slight drawback of the `np.newaxis` approach seems to be that I have to know the amount of elements of `d` beforehand. Right?

Or would there be a way to say something like `f = d * e[:, len(d) * np.newaxis]`

Comment: the number of dimensions, not the number of elements. If you don't want to assume anything about `d.ndim`, you should follow my second suggestion, and make the "common" dimension (in your example, the `3`), the last (i.e. d.shape = (2,2,3)).  That way, `e` is broadcast-able to `d`'s shape.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, please ignore that last remark of mine. I was going to delete it if you hadn't replied to it.
I did something else wrong in my code which got me off.
I got my mind tangled up in the dimensions... ;-/